# building cordova app for windows phone

Tags: windows, cordova, windows-phone-8, build, windows-phone

I'm trying to build a cordova app for the windows phone,

when I run

```
cordova build windows --release
```

it builds the app just fine, but when I go to the folder `c:/users/name/docs/proj/platform/windows` theres only one `.sln` file. It doesn't get updated after the build. When I open this file to build it to my test device I get the following error:

```
Error       DEP6701 : Bootstrapping failed with unexpected error: 'Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.'.    CordovaApp.Windows10
```

according to - https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/win8/

the

```
cordova build windows --release
```

build command should generate a new `.sln` file, but I said file isn't being generated, nor is the existing file being updated.

---Update---
I can now open the .sln file that cordova creates, but I can't publish the `CordovaApp.Windows10 (UW)` project because there's not publish option

Comment: please use visual studio 2015 ..

Comment: then try to run direct form cmd.. open your project and in that you have seperate directory for windows phone open it and then you can fins vs support file in it open it and then run from vs2015 after connect device with system or you can run in simulator

Comment: when I open cordovaapp.windows10.jsproj I get the DEP6701 error

Comment: try to open only windows.phone.jsproj or windows.phone8.jsproj

Comment: I opened CordovaApp.Phone.jsproj, and ran it to build to my windows phone but I get the 6701DEP error and a APPX4001 warning that says that the build property of appxbundleplatform is not explicitly set

Comment: @Gerwin Just wondering if you could solve problem and build app for window 10.